# Cart Not Automatically Updating After Adding items to Cart

Tags: php, ajax, shopify, liquid, cart

I have been working on modifying the following code to remove the popup window when clicking the "Quick Add to Cart" button. I have successfully removed the popup, but now I'm facing a new issue. The cart items is not updating automatically( not showing up) unless I manually refresh the page. I have Attached a click event listener to the cart icon to update cart items, but that didnt worked for me.

```
// Function to update the cart items inside the cart drawer
function updateCartItems(cart) {
    const cartItemsContainer = document.getElementById('cart-items-container');

    // Clear the current cart items
    while (cartItemsContainer.firstChild) {
        cartItemsContainer.removeChild(cartItemsContainer.firstChild);
    }

    // Add the updated cart items
    cart.items.forEach(item => {
        const cartItemElement = document.createElement('div');
        cartItemElement.textContent = item.title + ' - ' + item.quantity; // Customize how you want to display the items
        cartItemsContainer.appendChild(cartItemElement);
    });
}

function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(cart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
  //              cartRecommended(pro_id);
                
                // Update the cart items inside the cart drawer immediately
                updateCartItems(cart);
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:refresh', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    detail: {
                        variant: cart
                    }
                }));
            }, 1200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");

            }, 1600);
            setTimeout(function() {
    //            $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active');
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

// Listen for the 'cart:refresh' event and update the cart count
document.addEventListener('cart:refresh', function() {
    $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
        const cartCount = cart.item_count || 0;
        const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];
        if (CartCount) {
            CartCount.innerHTML = cartCount;
        }
    });
});

// Attach click event listener to the cart icon to update cart items when clicked
const cartIcon = document.querySelector('.cart-icon');
if (cartIcon) {
    cartIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Fetch the cart data and update the cart items when the cart icon is clicked
        $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(cart) {
            updateCartItems(cart); // Update the cart items inside the cart drawer
        });
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is happening when it doesn't work?

Comment: hello dear ryanwebjackson...i updated the post above, so i displayed how the side bar is empty even if i add items through quick add button, and how when i hard refresh the page, i got the items correctly displayed in the cart